# Laravel 5 middleware auth always fails and redirects to login

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.1, laravel-middleware, laravel-authorization

I am authenticating my user and redirecting him to dashboard if credentials are correct. I want to secure the dashboard route and added middleware auth, but now it always redirects to login page.

**Routes.php**

```
Route::get('login', array('uses' => 'HomeController@showLogin'));
Route::post('login', array('uses' => 'HomeController@doLogin'));
Route::get('logout', array('uses' => 'HomeController@doLogout'));

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('dashboard');
    });
    Route::get('dashboard', function () {
        return view('dashboard');
    });
});
```

HomeController.php

```
public function showLogin(){
    return View::make('login');
}

public function doLogin(Request $request){
    $rules = array(
        'email'    => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|alphaNum|min:3'
    );
    $validator = Validator::make($request::all(), $rules);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('login')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withRequest($request::except('password'));
    }
    else {
        $userdata = array(
            'email'     => $request::get('email'),
            'password'  => $request::get('password')
            /*'password' => Hash::make($request::get('password'))*/
        );
        if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {
            $userid = Auth::id();
            return redirect()->intended('/');
        } else {
            return Redirect::to('login');
        }
    }
}

public function doLogout()
{
    Auth::logout();
    return Redirect::to('login');
}
```

Middleware **Authenticate.php**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            return redirect()->guest('login');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Middleware **RedirectIfAuthenticated.php**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: looks like your session is not persisting. you can confirm that by dd(Auth::attempt($userdata)) before redirecting. if the value is true then you're sessions are not working correctly

Comment: I returned dd(Auth::attempt($userdata)) - its giving true..what do I do to correct it

Comment: search for "laravel session not persisting" on google

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why your code is not working, but you can try replace:

```
if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {
    $userid = Auth::id();
    return redirect()->intended('/');
}
```

with:

```
if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {
    $userid = Auth::id();
    return redirect('dashboard');
}
```

From the [API Docs of intended method](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Routing/Redirector.html#method_intended):

> Create a new redirect response to the previously intended location.

is giving some error to you as it is going back to the previous location and not to the next location.

---

**UPDATE 1:**

I would have gone with the following approach.

Make your own middleware called `UserAlreadyLoggedIn`

```
php artisan make:middleware UserAlreadyLoggedIn
```

Open `UserAlreadyLoggedIn.php` and update handle method with the below code:

```
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(auth()->check()) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect('login');
}
```

Register it in `app/Http/Kernel.php` file inside `$routeMiddleware` array:

```
$routeMiddleware = [
    'user_already_logged_in' => \App\Http\Middleware\UserAlreadyLoggedIn::class,
];
```

Separate the already logged in user in controller by making `UserSessionsController`

```
php artisan make:controller UserSessionsController --plain
```

Inside `UserSessionsController` place the `__constructor` method:

```
/**
 * Check if the user is already logged in.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('user_already_logged_in');
}
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('login', 'HomeController@showLogin');
Route::post('login', 'HomeController@doLogin');
Route::get('logout', 'HomeController@doLogout');

// Replace the dashboard code inside the dashboard method..
Route::get('dashboard', 'UserSessionsController@dashboard');
```

Again I would have created a middleware called `UserIsAGuest` and would have replaced the `if` block inside the `handle` method:

```
if(auth()->guest()) {
    return $next($request);
}
return redirect('dashboard');
```

And then inside the `HomeController`'s `__construct` method:

```
/**
 * Check if the user is already logged in.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    // Register the middleware in Kernel.php file
    $this->middleware('user_is_guest');
}
```

Hope this helps you out. Happy Coding. Cheers.

Comment: Kindly have a look at the **UPDATE 1**. Not sure whether this is what you are looking for. May be that can help you out. Give it a shot!

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for being late to the party, but after a long search for me, I had to change my middleware from `['middleware' => 'auth]` to `['middleware' => 'auth:web']`

I hope this helps out